# To remove line based on string

Tags: shell, unix

I have file like test.yaml file, the text content in the file like below.

```
servers:
  - uri: "http://demo.nginx1.com/status"
    name: "NGinX Monitor1"
  - uri: "http://demo.nginx2.com/status"
    name: "NGinX Monitor2"
```

I want to remove  - uri line and immediate next line (start with name:) where host name = demo.nginx1.com.
I want out put like below.

```
servers:
  - uri: "http://demo.nginx2.com/status"
    name: "NGinX Monitor2"
```

I tied like below..
cat test.yaml | grep -v demo.nginx1.com | grep -v Monitor1 >> test_back.yaml
mv test_back.yaml test.yaml

I am getting expected out put. But it's re creating the file and I don't want to re create the file

Please help me with suitable command that i can use..

Comment: Can you format your text exactly how it is in your file? You have written it as  a single line, but in your explanation you mention several lines (immediate next line).

Comment: ######################
servers: 
    - uri: "http://demo.nginx1.com/status" 
       name: "NGinX Monitor1"
     - uri: "http://demo.nginx2.com/status" 
       name: "NGinX Monitor2"
###########

Comment: so it's a single line then? and you want to remove parts of the line, not lines, correct? what should it look like after you have removed the parts you are not interested in?

Comment: No, in my file it has 5 lines.. line one) servers: line two) -uri: xxxxx line three) name: xx etc

Comment: Why not just use a yaml parser?

Comment: servers:
  - uri: "http://demo.nginx2.com/status"
    name: "NGinX Monitor2"
I am looking out put like below..

Comment: We don't have yaml parser in our box..

Comment: Please edit the question when you need to add further info. Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple logic using `GNU sed`

```
sed '/demo.nginx1.com/,+1 d' test.yaml
servers:
  - uri: "http://demo.nginx2.com/status"
    name: "NGinX Monitor2"
```

For `in-place` replacement, add a `-i` flag as `-i.bak`

```
sed -i.bak '/demo.nginx1.com/,+1 d' test.yaml
```

To see the in-place replacement:-

```
cat test.yaml
servers:
  - uri: "http://demo.nginx2.com/status"
    name: "NGinX Monitor2"
```

Comment: Hi !! i am getting value like variable,,, i hope it doesn't work if give command like below.. 
NGHOST=demo.nginx1.com
sed '/$NGHOST/,+1 d' test.yaml..

Comment: upvote, simplest answer. Just watch out for the use of non standard +1 modifier, it won't work on non-gnu sed like on OS X. You can use gsed instead.

Comment: @SureshchandraJarugula: If you are using `GNU sed`, use double-quotes like `sed "/$NGHOST/,+1 d" test.yaml`

Comment: If i use double-quotes it whitening below error.
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown command: `/'

Comment: Can you output `sed --version` ? Are you using `GNU sed`?

Comment: sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.

GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-gnu-utils@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.

Answer (score 0):

As I dislike using regular expressions to hack something you can parse - here's how I'd tackle it, using `perl` and the `YAML` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML;
use Data::Dumper;

#load yaml by reading files specified as args to stdin,
#or piped in. (Just like how you'd use 'sed')
my $config = Load ( do { local $/ ; <>} );

#output data structure for debug
print Dumper $config;

#use grep to filter the uri you don't want. 
@{$config -> {servers}} = grep { not $_ -> {uri} =~ m/demo.nginx2/ } @{$config -> {servers}};

#resultant data structure
print Dumper $config;
#output YAML to STDOUT
print Dump $config;
```